# Writing code for function / smiles in python

Tags: python, function

I wrote the following code, but when I run the test underneath it classifies all the chemicals as "None". I don't understand how to fix this. When I replace "smiles" with "test" and run the test then the output is correct.

```
def hydrocarbon_group(smiles):
    # your code here:
    if "=" in smiles:
        smiles = "alkene"
        #print(smiles, "is an alkene") 
    else:
        if "1" in smiles:
            smiles = "cycloalkane"
            #print(smiles, "is a cycloalkane")
        else:
            if "#" in smiles:
                smiles = "alkyne"
                #print(smiles, "is an alkyne")
            else:
                if "C" in smiles:
                    smiles = "alkane"
                    #print(smiles, "is a alkane")
                else:
                    smiles = "None"
                    #print(smiles, "is none")
        
#test = "C"
#hydrocarbon_group(test)


# test your function by checking whether the output below is correct
print('methane is', hydrocarbon_group("C"))
print('propene is', hydrocarbon_group("C=CC"))
print('ethyne is', hydrocarbon_group('C#C'))
print('cyclobutane is', hydrocarbon_group('C#C'))
print('methyl isocyanate is', hydrocarbon_group('CN=C=O'))
```

Comment: Because your function does not return anything. Also, look up what `elif` does as your conditions are exactly the reason for it.

Comment: Add `return smiles` at the end of your function

Comment: Also, probably look into dictionaries; with `classification = {"=": "alkene", "1": "cycloalkene", "#": "alkyne", ...}` you only need a loop over the keys and a single condition.

Answer (score 0):

insert `return smiles` at the bottom of the function it should work.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a slightly different way to do what you're asking. It uses two steps as follows:

- In a list comprehension (essentially a one-line loop that creates a `list` of results for each iteration), record the result of a search for each of your key characters `'=1#C'` in `smiles`, and use the first successful search by accessing the element of the search results at index `0` (append a different character such as `' '` to the search results to cover the possibility that `smiles` is either empty or does not contain any of the key characters).
- Using Python's `match` statement and `case` blocks, test for each of the key characters sequentially until the first match.

```py
def hydrocarbon_group(smiles):        
    x = ''.join([c[:c in smiles] for c in '=1#C']+[' '])[0]
    match x:
        case "=": 
            return "alkene"
        case "1": 
            return "cycloalkane"
        case "#": 
            return "alkyne"
        case "C": 
            return "alkane"
        case _: 
            return None

print('methane is', hydrocarbon_group("C"))
print('propene is', hydrocarbon_group("C=CC"))
print('ethyne is', hydrocarbon_group('C#C'))
print('cyclobutane is', hydrocarbon_group('C#C'))
print('methyl isocyanate is', hydrocarbon_group('CN=C=O'))
```

Output:

```
methane is alkane
propene is alkene
ethyne is alkyne
cyclobutane is alkyne
methyl isocyanate is alkene
```

The reasons for preferring this approach to the one in your original code are:

- Does not rely on nested `if`/`else` blocks.
- `match`/`case` syntax provides a concise, readable expression of what conclusion to draw based on which key character was encountered.
- For someone who is new to Python, the "exercise" of trying out the `match` statement helps build new language skills.

Arguments against this approach could include:

- The list comprehension for detecting the first key character encountered in the desired sequence is too cryptic.
- `if`/`elif`/`else` would provide an alternative that is also readable (though not as concise as the `match` statement) and does not require the list comprehension.

Comment: another caveat might be that match case only works in python 3.10 or above

Answer (score 0):

Here is a version that seems to work.  Also, being a chemist I did recognize that you weren't making the most rigorous tests but made some minor corrections anyway - to your cyclobutane smiles and test, and around your alkene test as methyl isocyanate is not technically an alkene. Added oxygen as the null test.

```
def hydrocarbon_group(smiles):        
    if "C=C" in smiles: 
        return "alkene"
    if "C1" in smiles: 
        return "cycloalkane"
    if "#" in smiles: 
        return "alkyne"
    if "C" in smiles: 
        return "alkane"
    if '' in smiles: 
        return None


print('methane is', hydrocarbon_group("C"))
print('propene is', hydrocarbon_group("C=CC"))
print('ethyne is', hydrocarbon_group('C#C'))
print('cyclobutane is', hydrocarbon_group('C1CCC1'))
print('methyl isocyanate is', hydrocarbon_group('CN=C=O'))
print('oxygen is', hydrocarbon_group('O=O'))
```

Produces this:

```
methane is alkane
propene is alkene
ethyne is alkyne
cyclobutane is cycloalkane
methyl isocyanate is alkane
oxygen is None
```